# Neofetch : acces denied folder .config

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, oh-my-zsh

I need your help with an access issue with neofetch on my macOS.
Here the thing, I recently install neofetch on my terminal (oh-my-zsh), it works but, between the firts line (last login) and the logo that displays :

> mkdir: /Users/'MYUSERNAME'/.config/neofetch/: Permission denied
> /usr/local/bin/Neofetch: line 4476:
> /Users/'MYUSERNAME'/.config/neofetch/config.conf: Permission denied

And I don't know why, of course, I did many types of research on google before asking you.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the permissions for your config directory:

`sudo chmod -R 666 /Users/YOURUSERNAME/.config`

666 means Read-Write for all users.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything...Thanks anyway !

Comment: Could you try it again with 777? Just curious if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same as garritfra did but with that last directory line you have there worked for me on a windows 10 machine though. It may work for the mac as well?

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /Users/MYUSERNAME/.config/neofetch/config.conf
```

Replace MYUSERNAME with whatever is shown in the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bulletproof one-liner that solves the issue:

```
sudo chmod -R 710 $HOME/.config
```

Execute this command in a terminal session.

After restarting your terminal or, alternatively, sourcing your shell configuration file (assuming you have added the `neofetch` command to that file) with:

`source ~/.zshrc`

(replacing `~/.zshrc` with the path to your shell configuration file if you are using a different one), the error prompt should disappear.

Note that this only gives 'execute' permission to the 'group' class. There is no need, as the currently accepted answer suggests, to give 666 or 777 modes as that needlessly makes your system less secure (not to mention even no. octal figures such as 666 don't even work as they fail to give the required 'execute' permission, which requires an odd number bit).

Modes such as `730`, `750`, and `770` will work, but unless something changes in neofetch's future update that demands it, it is unnecessarily too generous and I wouldn't advise it.

Finally, there is absolutely no reason to give users in the 'other' class any permission to the `~/.config` directory (unless you have a very compelling reason to), and hence the last permission bit (3rd digit in the mode represented by octal numbers) should always remain 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was able to solve this in the following way:

1. Open up Finder
2. Reveal hidden folders & files by pressing CMD+>+SHIFT
3. Locate the .config folder and right click it and click 'get info'.
4. Under the sharing & permissions section click the small plus and just add the entire Administrators group and remember to change the permissions to read & write for the entire group.
   [neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxCYQ.png)